# Why -(A&B)=-A|-B

Tags: logic

Let me repeat that.

Why not (A and B) means not A or not B

I use | to mean **or** and & to mean **and**.

It seems that if the not (or - sign) enter the bracket it changes **or** into **and** and via versa.

How true is it?

Also what's about the extension of it?

Is -(A|B&C|D) = -A & -B | -C & -D

Basically I want the strongest theorem and if possible, the most elegant proof.

Comment: Look up DeMorgan's Law.

Comment: DeMorgans Law applies to logic, boolean algebra, set theory, etc. It finds applications though its proof in different contexts will differ.  It is true that $\neg(A\wedge B) = \neg A \vee \neg B$, but it is also true that $\neg(A\vee B) = \neg A \wedge \neg B$. As for extending these statements to multiple terms, it can be done but the operator has to be consistent: $\neg(A\wedge B \wedge C) = \neg A \vee \neg B \vee \neg C$.  When you mix and match, you break the rule... and you need to look at the distributive property.

Comment: Can anyone turns this into an answer

Answer (score 1):

Look up de Morgan's Law.  But, basically:

---

When it is not the case that both are true, then it must be the case that at least one among them is false.$$\lnot(A\land B)\models(\lnot A)\lor(\lnot B)$$

Likewise, when it is the case that at least one among them is false, then it must not be the case that both are true.$$(\lnot A)\lor(\lnot B)\models\lnot(A\land B)$$